# Can't enter text in Snoop for hosted WPF application

Tags: wpf, snoop

When I run Snoop against my application I am unable to enter any text within Snoop itself, i.e. nothing in the filter boxes above the controls or properties, and nothing in the property values.  I can paste text that's in my copy buffer, and I can even do this from the Ctrl+V keyboard command, so the keyboard input is clearly being received.

I don't know if it's relevant but the application in question is a WinForms application hosting a WPF control.  Against other applications I don't suffer this problem.

Comment: Are you using the most recent Snoop version? On a related note: someone was writing about your issue many years ago, I just don't know whether the presented fix actually went into the original snoop code: http://www.cplotts.com/2009/04/13/snoop-now-works-in-wpf-interop-scenarios-part-ii/

Comment: I am using the latest version downloaded from the CodePlex site, but I see that it is six years old.  Is that ok, or should I move to the version on the GitHub site?